# strftime() function showing incorrect time

Tags: php, function

The `strftime()` function in php is not showing the correct time on my system. I am running php on xampp. Its around 11 o'clock on my PC clock, but the function `strftime()` returns 19 when I execute the following code:-

```
echo 'Time is - '.strftime('%H');
```

Comment: well you're missing quotes around `%H`, but that shouldn't even run so maybe it's something else.  What's the date/timezone you have set in php.ini?

Comment: @tandu I havnt changed any settings from php.ini

Comment: Are you in the USA by any chance? I bet your php time zone is set to GMT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your servers time zone by executing an ini_set at the top:

`ini_set( 'date.timezone', 'Europe/Berlin' );`

If you're on a hosting account the server is likely in a different time zone than you are. Even if you're running something locally I usually find it's set differently.

https://www.php.net/timezones

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is an wrong timezone set in php.ini:
http://www.dedyisn.net/linux/how-to-setting-default-time-zone-in-apache-webserver-for-php/

date("H"); also gives wrong time?

Answer (score 0):

You can also set your default timezone with running the following line on every request. You can achieve this easily if you put it in like a config.php or header.php file of your project.

```
date_default_timezone_set ( string $timezone_identifier )
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Timezone names: http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php