# How to show time with php code with the right timezone

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I need to show current time on my site in my city Iran/Tehran

I'm using this code:

```
 <?php echo date('H:i'); ?>
```

but it doesn't show the right time.

my country timezone : iran/tehran

my city time now is : 17:45

but on the site it shows me : 23:15

I don't know what time zone my server is in & I can't change that, please help me.

Comment: This is askt so many times... For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503673/strftime-function-showing-incorrect-time/10503716#10503716

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to change timezone in you code like that:

```
date_default_timezone_set('you/timezone');
```

Comment: @MarkBaker `Asia/Tehran` is the same has `Iran`

Answer (score 7):

You can use `date_default_timezone_set` or `DateTimeZone`

Example

```
echo date('H:i'),PHP_EOL;

date_default_timezone_set('Iran');
echo date('H:i'),PHP_EOL;

//Or

$date = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone("Asia/Tehran"));
echo $date->format("H:i"),PHP_EOL;
```

Output

```
14:24 
17:54
17:54
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set it by adding or editing a .htaccess file in the document root folder of your website and adding this line php_value date.timezone (your timezone here)

Answer (score 0):

There is very elegant way of dealing with this, namely: `DateTimeZone::getOffset`. You may find detailed usage exaples here: http://php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.getoffset.php