# PHP set time zone to PDT

Tags: php, timezone

I have tried this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
echo $starttime =   date("m/d/Y H:i:s");
echo $endtime   =   date("m/d/Y H:i:s", strtotime('+3 hours', strtotime($startdate)));

// Output    
06/14/2014 04:23:25
06/14/2014 07:23:25

// It should be
06/14/2014 01:23:25
06/14/2014 04:23:25
```

but it shows +3 hours from PDT time. I have read Pacific Time Zones [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.pacific.php) but I'm still unable to show time according to PDT.

One approach could be to subtract 3 hours from the time but isn't there any way to do it like this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('<PDT_Time>');
```

Comment: Show the code you're using to print a date, and what the output is that looks wrong. America/Los_Angeles should give the correct results.

Comment: Add e, P or T (or all three) to your date format to check the dates are in the correct zone. Also check your system clock, it may be wrong.

Comment: By using "e P T", America/New_York -04:00 EDT is shown with the date, still unable to show PDT. IMHO, subtracting 3 hours would just do fine.

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?  You need PHP 5.1.2 or above for this to work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php - date\_default\_timezone\_set not working, but ini\_set 'date.timezone' does. Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15096297/php-date-default-timezone-set-not-working-but-ini-set-date-timezone-does-w)

Comment: @Matt Currently, it is 5.3.9.