# Php wrong timezone

Tags: php, time

I have edited my php.ini file with this:

```
date.timezone = 'Europe/Kiev'
```

But when I am calling

```
date("Y-m-d H:i");
```

It returns 2018-10-15 09:09 when it's 12:09 in my country. How to change php timezone? I'm running on debian, and debian time is right

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Timezone conversion in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505681/timezone-conversion-in-php)

Comment: Make sure you have restart your server after made this change

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change default time zone in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27348112/how-to-change-default-time-zone-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

just use below function in your script ,it will set default time zone.

```
date_default_timezone_set("europe/kiev");
```